# Multiple COUNT columns in cosmos DB GROUP BY query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to use multiple `COUNT` columns in cosmos DB `GROUP BY` query. I have tried with a query something like this.

```
SELECT c.departmentName,
CASE WHEN c.age > 50 THEN COUNT(c.EmpId) ELSE 0 END AS category1,
CASE WHEN c.age <= 50 THEN COUNT(c.EmpId) ELSE 0 END AS category2
FROM c
GROUP BY c.departmentName
```

But I'm getting error message:

> "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'CASE'."

How can I apply multiple `COUNT` columns by filtering a property?

Comment: Side note: You have a *boundary condition* issue. Nobody with `age = 50` will be counted, as it satisfies neither condition.

Comment: I would suggest not tagging SQL for CosmosDB No SQL API questions as the dialect supported by CosmosDB is quite different from SQL in most relational databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CosmosDB NoSQL API query syntax does not support `CASE`.

To write this in CosmosDB compatible syntax you could use the [Ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/ternary-coalesce-operators#ternary-operator)

```
SELECT c.departmentName,
       SUM(c.age <= 49 ? 1 : 0)  AS category1,
       SUM(c.age = 50  ? 1 : 0)  AS the_ignored,
       SUM(c.age >  50 ? 1 : 0)  AS category2
FROM c
GROUP BY c.departmentName
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more succinct way to do it, but I usually do something like this:

(if you want to count records even when c.EmpID is null, just omit that condition)

```
SELECT c.departmentName,
       sum(
       CASE WHEN c.age > 50 and c.EmpId is not null 
            THEN 1
        END) AS category1,
       sum(
       CASE WHEN c.age <= 49 and c.EmpId is not null 
            THEN 1
        END) AS category2
  FROM c
 GROUP 
    BY c.departmentName;
```

Edit:

If you want to do the count and have implicit handling of nulls

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/blL66rbz

```
create table c 
  (
    departmentName varchar(100),
    age integer,
    empID integer
  );

insert into c values 
  ('Accounting', 53, 1),
  ('Accounting', 48, 2),
  ('Accounting', 30, null),
  ('Accounting', 71, 6),
  ('IT', 25, 3),
  ('IT', 32, 4),
  ('IT', 51, 5);

select c.departmentName,
       count(case when c.age >= 50 then c.empID end) as count50orOver,
       count(case when c.age <= 49 then c.empID end) as countUnder50
  from c
 group
    by c.departmentName
```

Comment: I think the last form is best. It is clearer to the reader that you are performing a count, when the count() function is used.  (And as a side note, [the three stooges are hiding somewhere](https://dbfiddle.uk/rP8gIPqZ).)

Comment: @TN Merp. Good catch!

Comment: @TN In my defense, that was OP's condition. Maybe there's a reason we're singling out 50 year olds.

Comment: fyi `case` isn't a keyword with Cosmos DB, nor is `create`

Comment: @DavidMakogon Ah, good to know, thank you for the correction. At some point there was a sql-server tag in mix so I wrote it up for that.

Comment: @Error_2646 - Yeah there was a [tag:sql] tag that I just removed, as this isn't a generic SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a common format for `conditional aggregation`. I don't have access to a Cosmos DB, but would imagine it works.

```
select 
 c.departmentName, 
 sum(case when c.age > 50 then 1 else 0 end) as category1, 
 sum(case when c.age <= 49 then 1 else 0 end) as category2
from table c
where c.age is not null 
group by c.departmentName
```

Comment: Nope - no such `CASE` keyword in Cosmos DB's query language.